# How to ignore an autocmd in vim's undo history?

Tags: vim, undo

I have the following autocommand, which basically strips whitespace at the end of each line. Unfortunately, at each save, it inserts a step into the undo to jump to the beginning to the file, which is quite annoying. Is there a way to make vim ignore jumping around in the following command, so that undoing keeps the cursor in position?

```
autocmd BufWritePre *
    \ let s:bufwritepre_currline = line('.') |
    \ let s:bufwritepre_currcol = col('.')   |
    \ silent %s/\s*$//                       |
    \ call cursor(s:bufwritepre_currline, s:bufwritepre_currcol)
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but for restoring cursor position, `winsaveview()`/`winrestview()` is probably preferable over the `line()`/`col()`/`cursor()` solution given in your example.

Comment: Thanks @SørenLøvborg, your comment was the solution for me